# Writing A Macro that checks that a cell is populated, then it writes the corresponding information to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently writing a macro for an item list that checks to see if an item is chosen, and if it is chosen, it will transmit all of the corresponding item information to another sheet. My code is not producing any errors but it also isn't doing what I want it to. I'm still kind of learning how to use VBA syntax so I might be missing something very simple but here is my code

```
Sub ExportCableTray()

Dim UOM As Range
Dim QTY  As Range
Dim MTL As Range
Dim DMT As Range
Dim IT As Range
Dim IST As Range
Dim num As Range
Dim des As Range



Dim rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim Seq As Integer

Seq = 1 'Defines the Seq column in the Export Sheet
i = 8 'counter that goes through the cable tray
j = 12 'counter that decides the row value for the Export Sheet



Set rng = Sheets("Cable Tray").Range("I8:I185")


For Each Cell In rng
    If Len(Cell) <> 0 Then

                Set UOM = Sheets("Cable Tray").Cells(i, 5)
                Set QTY = Sheets("Cable Tray").Cells(i, 15)
                Set MTL = Sheets("Cable Tray").Cells(i, 7)
                Set DMT = Sheets("Cable Tray").Cells(i, 8)
                Set IT = Sheets("Cable Tray").Cells(i, 9)
                Set IST = Sheets("Cable Tray").Cells(i, 10)
                Set num = Sheets("Cable Tray").Cells(i, 2)
                Set des = Sheets("Cable Tray").Cells(i, 3)


                UOM.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Export Sheet").Cells(j, 4)
                QTY.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Export Sheet").Cells(j, 5)
                MTL.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Export Sheet").Cells(j, 6)
                DMT.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Export Sheet").Cells(j, 7)
                IT.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Export Sheet").Cells(j, 8)
                IST.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Export Sheet").Cells(j, 9)
                Sheets("Export Sheet").Cells(j, 1).Value = Seq
                num.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Export Sheet").Cells(j, 2)
                des.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Export Sheet").Cells(j, 3)

                i = i + 1
                Seq = Seq + 1
                j = j + 1



      End If

      Next Cell

End Sub
```

It's possible that I'm over complicating things and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also to note that the sheet that is being read from is "Cable Tray" with range (I8:185) and it needs to be writing to the "Export" sheet starting at row 12.

Answer (score 0):

i = i + 1 needs to go outside the IF statement, since you need to keep checking cells even if the current cell is blank. So you last few lines should rewad

```
            Seq = Seq + 1
            j = j + 1

  End If
  i = i + 1
  Next Cell
```

Comment: This was definitely part of it however the code still isn't writing anything to my second sheet.  Am I using the correct syntax to write to a separate sheet within my workbook?

Comment: Syntax looks fine - trying running the code with F8 to step through and watch what happens when it gets to the copy